# How to print a SQLite table in C in table format

Tags: c, sqlite

It is fairly well documented that you can use a `callback()` function in C to iteratively print SQLite table column names and values with a format like this:

```
ID = 1
COLUMN_A = <value>
COLUMN_B = <value>

ID = 2
COLUMN_A = <value>
COLUMN _B = <value>
```

However, this format takes up more vertical space than necessary and doesn't preserve the visual structure of a table. Is there a simple, direct way to print a SQLite table in C that preserves the table structure?

Comment: Just print out values in rows instead of one value per line?

Answer (score 0):

I once played with [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org) in C++ and created a little calculator app which saves your variables in a database. I used their [quickstart](https://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html) example as reference. I used a somewhat similar approach for printing the data.

I print some lines with `+`, `-` and `|` signs to make it look like a real table even when printing on a simple terminal using ascii.

The important part of printing a nicely formatted table are those lines/separators and for that you need to be able to check if you are in the first row or not. For this I use the `void*` argument to the `callback` function. This also lets me return the number of columns in the table so I can print a separator at the end as well.

```
struct TableData {
    int currentRow;
    int columns;
    int columnWidth;
};

void printTableSeparator(const int columns, const int width) {
    for (int i = 0; i < columns; ++i) {
        printf("+");
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
            printf("-");
        }
    }
    printf("+\n");
}

void printTableRow(const int columns, const int width, const char** itemNames) {
    for (int i = 0; i < columns; ++i) {
        printf("|%-*.*s", width, width, itemNames[i] ? itemNames[i] : "NULL");
    }
    printf("|\n");
}

int callback(void* data, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName) {
    struct TableData* table = data;

    if (table->currentRow == 0) {
        table->columns = argc;

        printTableSeparator(argc, table->columnWidth);
        printTableRow(argc, table->columnWidth, azColName);
        printTableSeparator(argc, table->columnWidth);
    }

    printTableRow(argc, table->columnWidth, argv);

    table->currentRow++;
    return 0;
}

int exec_wrapper(sqlite3* db, const char* sql, char** errmsg) {
    struct TableData table = { 0 };
    table.columnWidth = 15;

    int ret = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, &table, errmsg);
    printTableSeparator(table.columns, table.columnWidth);

    return ret;
}
```

Executing this on a set of my variables table in the database gets me the following result:

```
+---------------+---------------+
|name           |value          |
+---------------+---------------+
|pi             |3.14159        |
|e              |2.71828        |
|g              |9.80665        |
|ans            |8.0            |
|area           |138.23         |
|var            |6.40318        |
+---------------+---------------+
```